# Defining regular expression

Tags: python, regex

If below is the string:

```
"AN : GSHJ488GL67 Customer : sh3893 Acnt No : cgk379gu Name : xyz"
```

I want to extract only the alphanumeric string following `'AN : '` or `'Acnt No : '`.

I want this regex for a python script.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here should __show research effort or attempts__. Please take a __[tour]__.

Comment: Why use a regex? Just split on " " and take the appropriate elements of the resulting list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) for this..

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'AN : GSHJ488GL67 Customer : sh3893 Acnt No : cgk379gu Name : xyz'
>>> re.findall(r'\b(?:AN|Acnt No) : (\w+)', s)
['GSHJ488GL67', 'cgk379gu']
```

**Explanation**:

```
\b         # the boundary between a word character and not a word character
(?:        # group, but do not capture:
  AN       #   'AN'
 |         #  OR
  Acnt No  #   'Acnt No'
)          # end of grouping
 :         #   ' : '
(          # group and capture to \1:
  \w+      #   word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times)
)          # end of \1
```

Answer (score 1):

As Marc suggests, using split(" ") is the simplest solution here. The regex approach requires some care. <s>Eg, what happens if we use hwnd's regex pattern and one of the data fields end in "AN"?</s>

Comment: Is it possible to use finditer?

Comment: The finditer method is probably overkill, here. But I'm confused: in your original post you said that you want "the alphanumeric string following 'AN : ' or 'Acnt No : '". But now you're complaining that "This prints AN and Acnt No also.". So what do you _actually_ want your code to do?

Answer (score 0):

Incase other values are required as well. You can convert the string to dict and then call them by various keys

```
import re                                                                   
import json                                                                 
data = "AN : GSHJ488GL67 Customer : sh3893 Acnt No : cgk379gu Name : xyz"   
data = re.sub("\s*:\s*(\w+)\s*", r'":"\1" ,"', data)                        
data = '{"'+data[:-3]+'}'                                                   
mapping = json.loads(data)                                                  
print mapping                                                               
print mapping["Acnt No"]                                                    
print mapping["AN"]
```

**output**

```
{'Customer': 'sh3893', 'Acnt No': 'cgk379gu', 'Name': 'xyz', 'AN': 'GSHJ488GL67'}
cgk379gu
GSHJ488GL67
```